# Why my angularJS errors are showing like this in the firefox console and firebug?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I'm working in an `angularjs` application but somehow this plugin 'smart-table' it's not being added to my app modules array but that's not the problem, I want to know why firefox and firebug show the error like this, and if there's a way to fix this

this is how firefox and firebug show the error in the console. I tried using only the firefox console without a firebug but it's the same they both show the error the same way

why it appears all those percentage symbols and big letter cases 'F'?

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=SistemaActividades&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dsmart-table%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dsmart-table%250AG%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A251%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A494%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A117%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A134%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A331%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A488%250Aeb%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A249%250Ayc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Ayc%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250AZd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A83%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A294%253A192%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A175%253A62%250AIf%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A35%253A365%250AHf%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.4.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A35%253A314%250A%0AG%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2F
```

Comment: If I understand your questions, that is just how angular shows errors. If you click on it, it will take you to angular's doc web site with the error shown

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown by angular when it cant find the module that you are trying to pass, it is actually a link to angular docs that describe the error.

Try to check if the js of smart table is loaded before you pass to your app

load angular.js, than smarttable.js
then use it 
`angular.module('myApp',['smart-table']`

Comment: de module is include like this `angular.module('SistemaActividades', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'smart-table', 'wt.responsive']);` and the script is added at the end of my index page but still it shows the same hard to read error, but when I click the it doesn't take me to the angularjs website it doesn't do anything, but I know what are you talking about, with some errors it takes to the angularjs website

Comment: The error only shows up when you add smart-table? try to remove the modules one by one and check when it stops working maybe you have more than one error.
Also make sure to load modules before use them.

"In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute." from the docs

Comment: I would try that, but I think that have to do something with spring secuirty since this error is showing in the login page and it's not showing in the index page after being authenticated , but anyways is it normal to that those error are all scramble like that or is something with firefox

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when you have a dependency that you that you have not included the proper files for. This can happen when using third-party modules that you find from repositories.

Often times the module that you use will have it's own dependencies with it's own required files as well. Just ensure that all your dependencies are fulfilled.